# objective-c variable length array global scope

Tags: iphone, objective-c, variables, scope, global

is it possible to declare a variable length array with global scope in objective-c?

I'm making a game with a world class, which initializes the world map as a three dimensional integer array. while it's only a two dimensional side scroller, the third dimension of the list states which kinda of block goes at the coordinate given by the first two dimensions

after the initialization function, a method nextFrame: is scheduled (I'm using cocos2d and the CCDirector schedule method). I was wondering how to pass the int[][][] map array from the initialization function to the nextFrame function

I tried using global (static keyword) declaration, but got an error saying that global arrays cannot be variable length

the actual line of code I'm referring to is:

```
int map[xmax][ymax][3];
```

where xmax and ymax are the farthest x and y coordinates in the list of coordinates that defines the stage.

I'd like to somehow pass them to nextFrame:, which is scheduled in

```
[self schedule:@selector(nextFrame:)];
```

I realize I can use NSMutableArray, but NSMutableArray is kinda a headache for 3-dimensional lists of integers (I have to use wrapper numbers for everything...). is there any way to do this with integer arrays?

Comment: I'm not a games developer so I may not understand some of the issues involved but can you not create a `WorldMap` class that uses NSMutableArray but just abstracts its use with a nice API?

Comment: that's a good point. I guess I never really thought of that.

Comment: is it better to be a subclass of NSMutableArray, or just have NSMutableArray as an instance variable

Comment: I am assuming you will not be adding any functionality to `NSMutableArray` just providing a convenient API for setting and getting the information you want. Therefore an ivar should be fine. This is of course only a suggestion I was hoping some people might chime in and give their thoughts on it

Comment: ok well that should work. Thanks for the suggestion

I'm kinda new to stack overflow. is it considered a waste of a comment just to say thanks? I mean there's a minimum length so that excludes the word "thanks"

Comment: by the way I'm not a games developer either. just a student about to enter college with nothing better to do over the summer than make a game with friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a statically allocated global array of dynamic dimensions in C (of which Objective C is a clean superset).  But you can use a global array of any length or size (up to available memory) at runtime by using a global pointer, malloc, and array indexing arithmetic.

```
static int *map = NULL;

...
map = malloc (dim1 * dim2 * dim3 * sizeof(int));  // in some initialization method

if (map == NULL) { /* handle error */ }    // before first array access

...
myElement = map[ index3 + dim2 * ( index2 + dim1 * index1 ) ];  // some macro might be suitable here
```

Or you could make Objective C getter and setter methods that checks the array and array bounds on every access, since a method can return plain C data types.

Another option, if you know the max dimensions you want to have available and are willing to use (waste) that amount of memory, is to just statically allocate the max array, and throw an exception if the program tries to set up something larger than your allowed max.

Comment: if I did the method you indicated, could I possibly do something similar to myElement = map[index1][index2][index3] or would that not work?

Comment: my guess is it wouldn't, but I'm not sure exactly how multidimensional arrays are structured in memory

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using global (static keyword)
>   declaration, but got an error saying
>   that global arrays cannot be variable
>   length

But global array pointers can point to arrays of variable length.